# Suppose we have a chair with $n$ legs and it stands with all legs irrespective of floor's quality i.e smoothness,evenness, then what is $n$?

Tags: permutations

Suppose we have a chair with $n$ legs and it stands with all legs irrespective of floor's quality i.e smoothness,evenness, then what is $n$?

1)2

2)3

3)4

4)5

I have no clue what they want to say, thank you for helping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer must be 3, because a chair cannot stand on 2 legs and it is easy to construct a counterexample where a chair stands on 3 of its 4 (or 5) legs. Just imagine there to be a hole underneath the other legs.